# Text not displayed correctly in R Shiny app (although no code error is shown but it's not doing what I write)

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a simple income-search tool where individuals can enter their job title, monthly wage, and city, and as an output they can learn how their wages compare to the median wage of other individuals in their geographic area controlling for their job title.
print data

```
dput(df[1:10,c(1,2,3,4,5,6)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(grp = c("Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant"), monthly_income = c(8000, 2500, 8500, 4500, 35000, 5500, 10000, 7000, 12000, 4000), yrs_experience = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 0, 3, 3, NA), location = c("Portland", "Portland", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Portland", "Portland", "Seattle"), qualifications = c("no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference"), gender_preferences = c("no_gender_preference", "female", "female", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the current code, which I have edited to incorporate the useful suggestions below and it works well without errors but it's not displaying the text I would like to see for each job title.

```
library(shiny)
# library(shinydashboard)
# library(shinyWidgets)
#library(readxl)


ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    #textInput("grp", "Occupation"), # dropdown menu for job titles
    selectizeInput(
      "grp",
      "Occupation",
      sort(salary_test_data$grp), 
      choices = append("", sort(unique(
        salary_test_data$grp
      ))),
      selected = "",
      multiple = F
    ),
    #choices = sort(unique(salary_test_data$grp)),
    selectizeInput("qualifications",
                   "Qualifications",
                   choices = append("", sort(
                     unique(salary_test_data$qualifications)
                   ))),
    verbatimTextOutput("comparison_results"),
    sliderInput(
       "yrs_experience",
      "Years of Experience",
       min = 0,
       max = 9,
       value = 0,
       post = " Year(s)"
     ),
    selectizeInput("location",
                   "City",
                   choices = append("", sort(
                     unique(salary_test_data$location)
                   ))),
    numericInput("monthly_income", "Monthly Pay", value = 0),
    actionButton("compare_btn", "Compare Salary")
  ),

mainPanel(plotOutput("salary_plot")
)
))


server <- function(input, output) {
  comparison_results <-
    eventReactive(input$compare_btn, {
      user_Occupation <- input$grp
      user_experience <- input$yrs_experience
      user_monthly_pay <- input$monthly_income
      user_location <- input$location
      user_qualification <- input$qualifications
      
      filtered_data <- salary_test_data[salary_test_data$grp == user_Occupation &
                                          salary_test_data$location == user_location &
                                          salary_test_data$qualifications == user_qualification &
                                          salary_test_data$yrs_experience == user_experience, ]
      
      if (nrow(filtered_data) > 0) {
        if (user_monthly_pay >= median(filtered_data$monthly_income)) {
          "Your monthly salary is above the median income of workers employed in your profession,
        who share your qualifications, & city"  
        } else {
          "Your monthly salary is below the median income of workers employed in your profession,
        who share your qualifications, & city"
        }
      } else {
        "No data found for the given job title and/or city"
      }
    })
  
  output$comparison_results <- renderText({
    comparison_results()
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no `output` with name `comparison_results` only a variable with that name created inside the `observeEvent`. Instead you could use `eventReactive` and a `renderText` to create `output$comparison_results` which will then be displayed in your UI:

```
salary_test_data <- structure(list(grp = c("Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant", "Accountant"), monthly_income = c(8000, 2500, 8500, 4500, 35000, 5500, 10000, 7000, 12000, 4000), yrs_experience = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 0, 3, 3, NA), location = c("Portland", "Portland", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Portland", "Portland", "Seattle"), qualifications = c("no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference"), gender_preferences = c("no_gender_preference", "female", "female", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference", "no_gender_preference")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        "grp",
        "Occupation",
        sort(salary_test_data$grp),
        choices = append("", sort(unique(
          salary_test_data$grp
        ))),
        selected = "",
        multiple = F
      ),
      selectizeInput("qualifications",
        "Qualifications",
        choices = append("", sort(
          unique(salary_test_data$qualifications)
        ))
      ),
      sliderInput(
        "yrs_experience",
        "Years of Experience",
        min = 0,
        max = 9,
        value = 0,
        post = " Year(s)"
      ),
      selectizeInput("location",
        "City",
        choices = append("", sort(
          unique(salary_test_data$location)
        ))
      ),
      numericInput("monthly_income", "Monthly Pay", value = 0),
      actionButton("compare_btn", "Compare Salary")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("comparison_results")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  comparison_results <-
    eventReactive(input$compare_btn, {
      user_Occupation <- input$grp
      user_experience <- input$yrs_experience
      user_monthly_pay <- input$monthly_income
      user_location <- input$location
      user_qualification <- input$qualifications

      filtered_data <- salary_test_data[salary_test_data$grp == user_Occupation &
        salary_test_data$location == user_location &
        salary_test_data$qualifications == user_qualification &
        salary_test_data$yrs_experience == user_experience, ]

      if (nrow(filtered_data) > 0) {
        if (user_monthly_pay >= median(filtered_data$monthly_income)) {
          "Your monthly salary is above the median income of workers employed in your profession,
        who share your qualifications, & city in Saudi Arabia"
        } else {
          "Your monthly salary is below the median income of workers employed in your profession,
        who share your qualifications, & city in Saudi Arabia"
        }
      } else {
        "No data found for the given job title and/or city"
      }
    })

  output$comparison_results <- renderText({
    comparison_results()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, but I am still unfortunately facing the same problem. I have tried running your exact code above by itself, as well as running the entire code starting from: ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout.... However, I am still not getting any text output.

Comment: Sorry. Should have mentioned that I moved the `verbatimTextOutput` into the `mainPanel`. As is it will be displayed inside the sidebarPanel right above the slider input.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post to reflect what I think is your code, but I am not fully sure if this is what you ran, because I am still experiencing the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: I just have made an edit which include the UI code and checked that this will give the output shown in the screenshot.